# Use ODBC in PHP7.4 - Unable to locate package php7.4-odbc

Tags: php, apache, odbc, ubuntu-16.04

I need to use functions from PHPs ODBC library (like odbc_connect) on my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Server. Unfortunately, if I try to install php7.4-odbc with

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-odbc
```

is fails with

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-odbc
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-odbc'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-odbc'
```

How can I install PHPs ODBC package on this Server?

Comment: PHP 7.4 is not available for 16.04. You can try `apt install php-odbc` which should get you 7.0.

Comment: php-odbc is already installed. But how can I use this with my 7.4 installation? Or do I need to switch back to php 7.0?

Comment: How did you get PHP 7.4 installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: It's a vagrant box based on a puphpet file. When they changed to the new Ubuntu version we added some install scripts that now install php7.4-fpm and some more packages to use 7.4 on that Ubuntu version. But if I understand your question correctly you mention to use a (newer?) Ubuntu version?

Comment: _"When they changed to the new Ubuntu version"_ I'm confused. So is it running 16.04 or not? Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP 7.0, 18.04 comes with 7.2, 20.04 comes with 7.4.

Comment: I meant "when they last changed to the new Ubuntu version" ;). One of the problems is, that also puphpet is no longer under development, so on the last Ubuntu update of the vagrant box I needed to switch to fpm. And that was when I installed the 7.4-fpm on that machine.

Comment: Your vagrant box is probably using the 3rd party Ondrej PPA, which is how you were able to install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 in the past. However, that is a no-longer-supported version. You'll likely need to update the server to something reasonably modern, or maybe compile the extension from source.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-odbc
```